# Android: Removing items from a ListView/ArrayAdapter Activity

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list (of messages) and I want to give the user the ability to remove these items from the list. I have extended an `ArrayAdapter` and give it an `ArrayList` of my messages and would like to simply remove an item from that list and then refresh the `ListView` instead of reloading the entire list of sent messages. The problem is, if there's only one message and I remove it using `listAdapter.remove(messageObject)`, the adapter is still calling `getView()` and then throwing `NullPointerExceptions` all over the place. I'm not sure what the best way is to go about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently things go a little haywire if you don't override the getCount() function in your custom ArrayAdapter. I set it to the size of my ArrayList and now everything seems to be working correctly.