# How can I "set View" in right place where I remove an item in ListView (Android)

Tags: android, listview

I choose an item to remove from my `ListView`. And after the Item was removed, my `ListView` was scrolled back and display at the first Item.
I want my `ListView` display in right place where the Item I had removed (It like remove a contact in Android Contact list). How can I do that?

Comment: Any success with setSelection(int)?

Comment: Can I ask you more about how to "recalculating new indices and new item count" ? And sorry for the late reaction!

Comment: No problem, I'll try to help, but you have to be more specific about what exactly is the problem and what is your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to update your `ListView` display, after you remove an item, right?

When you remove the item, you have to modify your data adapter, and let the `ListView` change accordingly (something like the MVC pattern behavior). I've seen somewhat similar questions (and the corresponding answers :) ) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320108/android-removing-items-from-a-listview-arrayadapter-activity) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/19091af72b233ee3).

Edit:

Aha, in that case, try using `setSelection(int)`, after recalculating new indices and new item count.

Comment: I think my problem is something different from your given link. I have already update my Listview. But after update(refresh) the List display at First item (not the place where you have just delete the item). My List have more than 4000 rows, and I don't want my User scroll down again.